# How to execute the nord cms yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, content-management-system

Hi I have integrated Yii nord cms.. Here is my code

config.php

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.cms.CmsModule',
    'application.controllers.*',
        ),
   'modules'=>array(
'cms',
   ),
   'components'=>array(

   'urlManager'=>array(

    'rules'=>array(

        'page/<name>-<id:\d+>.html'=>'cms/node/page', // clean URLs for pages
    ),
        ),

'cms'=>array(
    'class'=>'cms.components.Cms',
),
```

In my site controller I have wriiten code like this

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {

        $this->widget('cms.widgets.CmsBlock',array('name'=>'bar'));
        $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));        
         }
```

I dont know how to run my nordcms. I have got empty output. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should put the widget in your view file, in this case, the index.php view file found in views/site/index.php.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget

Comment: I have got an error Cms: Failed to create node. Name "" is invalid.